# grouped bar graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have the data frame:

```
   Job  Answer
1   1   3
2   0   2
3   1   2
4   0   2
5   1   2
6   0   2
7   1   2
8   0   1
9   1   2
10  0   2
11  1   2
12  0   4
13  1   2
14  0   1
15  1   2
16  0   2
17  1   2
18  0   3
19  1   4
20  0   2
21  1   2
22  0   2
23  1   2
24  0   2
25  1   2
26  0   2
27  1   1
28  0   3
29  1   1
30  0   2
31  1   1
32  0   2
33  1   2
34  0   2
```

and I would like to make a grouped bar chart that on the x axis there's the answer and for each answer there will be 2 columns of Job 1 and 2. the y axis will be the frequency that the combination appeared.

I made the following:

```
ggplot(q10,aes(x=factor(Answer),y='',fill=factor(Job))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

but he only gives me one column for each answer...

Thanks for help..

Comment: `ggplot(q10,aes(x=factor(Answer), fill=factor(Job))) + geom_bar(position="dodge")`

Answer (score 0):

The `position_dodge` function should take care of that. Try this code.

```
ggplot(data=q10, aes(x=Answer, y='', fill=Job))
+ geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

The **position="dodge"** works by dodging overlaps by position the bars side-by-side.

Comment: thank for the help, but this doesn't work unless you remove the stat="identity" and only write position="dodge"